# "The title google has is "Cotack Goniometer".....and it should be "Contact Goniometer"...how do I suggest changes?

Tags: patent-services

In reference to the patent: [US655005](https://www.google.com/patents/US655005)

Answer (score 0):

On Google at the bottom right of the page there is a button that says "give feedback".
 But the error could be at the uspto, too. In that case you would gave to contact them directly. There is a Uspto link on the google page too, as this patent is pretty old the full text version is not available. I can't open the images from the smartphone, but you should check there first.